Android Compose OutlinedTextField -> show suggestion from Messaging App (SMS)
Before hand I was using an EditText in normal views. and when opening an "EditText" -> I would receive a suggestion to input code from SMS.

However now I am using an OutlinedTextField in Compose and it does not provide me that suggestion anymore.
Is there a way to fix this?
This is my OutlinedTextField:
OutlinedTextField(
                            value =  provisioningCode,
                            onValueChange = {
                                viewModel.updateProvisioningCode(it)
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier,
                            placeholder = {
                                Text(
                                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.code),
                                    style = style
                                )
                            },
                            isError = provisioningCode.isEmpty(),
                            textStyle = style,
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone),
                            colors = colors,
                        )

